# How to maxLength attribute for div or p tag in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

I would like to limit my tabel cell to 10 character how do i do that?
{some value} 
here tableCell is a div (styled component)

Comment: If it's greater than 10 characters what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is to conditionally render the table cell.

```
<div>
{someValue.length <= 10 ? someValue : someValue.substring(0, 10)}
</div>
```

The code I've written will check if the value of the string is 10 characters or less and if it is, show the value or if not, show the first 10 characters.

Comment: can we also use slice()? someValue.slice(0, someValue.length <= 10 ? 10 : someValue.length)

Comment: Yeah you could - substring and slice are pretty interchangeable. Below is a post on the differences. But the conditional rendering is {CONDITION ? TRUE : FALSE}. Your conditional returns should be flipped. I would personally not do it that way though because the code is a tad messier to read. If this helped solve the question, please mark it as the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring